# JSP - Saving a collection

Tags: java, jsp, struts, jstl

[Warning] I'm new to JSP/Struts/JSTL. This is probably a newbie question :)

I have a form that contains a collection:

```
public class ServiceForm extends AbstractForm
{   
    private List<SrvDO> allSrv = new ArrayList<SrvDO> ();  
}
```

I can see the object data correctly in my form using the JSP. The page displays 5 input box with the data from the database correctly:

```
<c:forEach items="${serviceForm.allSrv}" var="srv">                     
    <html:text name="srv" property="nbDays"/>   
 </c:forEach>   

<html:submit/>
```

But when I press the submit button, the form does not contains the updated data for "nbDays". I still see the same data as it was shown before the update. What am I missing that says to struts: for each srv, update the "nbDays" data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer on [the spring forum](http://forum.springframework.org/showthread.php?t=54509):

> Your form:input tag doesn't and
>   shouldn't know anything about the fact
>   that it is used inside another tag.
>   That is why you need to include the
>   index.

So the solution is:

```
<html:text property="allSrv[${srvSta.index}].nbDays"/>
```